# Flushing BD before testing. Setting lettuce terrain.py

Tags: python, django, django-south, lettuce

Using salad(lettuce) for testing, I followed [this tutorial](http://cilliano.com/blog/2011/02/07/django-bdd-with-lettuce-and-splinter/) and set my terraxin.py file as shown in the link. I installed south, did my initial migration and run the tests but I'm getting an error in the initial setup after the `flush` command when executing `migrate`, getting `DatabaseError: relation "xx_yy" already exists`.
Is the example in the link alright? Is there a better way to set the terrain.py file for correct testing?

Answer (score 0):

The command `call_command('syncdb', interactive=False, verbosity=0)` runs not simple `syncdb` but `syncdb --all` by default. That's why all your models get synced and you recieve this error.

As a solution you can skip `call_command('migrate', interactive=False, verbosity=0)` if you don't need to test your migrations.